# Webpack fails while require.ensure typescript file

Tags: angularjs, webpack, angular-ui-router

In the app i define my state like:

```
$stateProvider
.state('index', {
    url: '/',
    controller: 'indexController',
    resolve: {
        foo: ['$q', '$ocLazyLoad', function ($q, $ocLazyLoad) {
            let deferred = $q.defer();
            require.ensure([], function () {                                    
                let module = require('./index/test.ts')(angularRef);
                $ocLazyLoad.load({ name: 'myAppIndex' });               
                deferred.resolve(module);
            });         
            return deferred.promise;
        }]
   }
})
```

The webpack definition looks like this:

```
...
    module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: [
                { loader: 'babel-loader', query: { compact: true } },
            ]
        },             
        { test: /\.ts?$/, loader: "ts-loader" },

        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: "style-loader",
                use: [
                    { loader: 'css-loader', query: { modules: false, sourceMaps: false, minimize: true } }
                ]
            })
        }, {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: "style-loader",
                use: [
                    { loader: 'css-loader', query: { modules: false, sourceMaps: false, minimize: true } },
                    { loader: 'sass-loader', query: { sourceMaps: false } }
                ]
            })
        }, {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'raw-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }
    ]
....
```

dont forget the tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types/"
    ],

    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

but everytime i compile the script with webpack
"webpack-dev-server --inline --watch --devtool eval --progress --colors --content-base views"

i got this error

> main.bundle.js:1 TypeError: **webpack_require**(...) is not a function

The './index/test.ts' is getting called, inside of it there is a "console.log" which is getting called

So the big question is, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `require` argument. https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require-ensure

```
    require.ensure([], function (require) {                                    
        let module = require('./index/test.ts')(angularRef);
        $ocLazyLoad.load({ name: 'myAppIndex' });               
        deferred.resolve(module);
    });
```

Comment: i will definitly try this, but in two days (weekend). in the meantime, what is the purpose of this require argument?
If i do this with a .JS file everything is fine (even without this require argument)

Comment: @Benjamin maybe it worked because it was interpreted like regular static `require`. I have added a docs link in my answer.

Comment: thank you, this will work, also i had to update the oclazyload to a recent version. the only problem is that the generated chunk file in this case "0.js" is not getting updated when the correspondign typescript file is saved.
Webpack start to compile again, but the chunk-file is still the same, do you have any idea whats wrong?

Comment: @Benjamin if you use `webpack-dev-serve` the file will be saved in memory.

Comment: i forgot to mention that this code is served from VisualStudio, so VS serves the website (not the dev server from webpack), i am not sure if this is even possible to combine webpack-dev-server and visual studio, i tried to change the port for webpack-dev-server to Visual Studio's port, but that didnt work either

Comment: i did not work because of a misconfiguration, thanks anyway